# what is the efficient way to pass data from one component to multiple components?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template

Initially i thought of using subjects but the value won't change regularly. I just have to pass the user id in the beginning to multiple components. Which is the best way to pass? **@Input decorator or subjects?**

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Ramya, If you want to keep all the other components updated/synced with one component just use a service. Let the setter component set the value in the service and all other components can subscribe to it to get updated values whenever it is available

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service is the better way to pass data one component to multiple components, if you want to pass data from one parent component to multiple child components, in that case better way is @input decorator. If you want listen data changes in other components when passed data from other component in that case we can use subjects and subscribe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a **singleton** service (*provided in root module*).You can use BehaviaralSubject inside this service (if you want, can do without BehaviaralSubject). *@Input* can't use everywhere. It can only use when passing values from parent component to a child component.However The way of sharing data is completely depends on your requirements and the structure.